# Ajax in Laravel 5.2 not working

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to add ajax in my laravel 5.2 project for some days but I have not been able to. I need help/link/tutorial from anybody. Note that I googled many times in the mean time and follow the mentioned process but nothing happened.

Here's a piece of my code: 
Ajax:

```
$('#contact-sort').on('click', function () {

        //$this = $(this);

       // alert($this.data('id'));

        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/abc',
            data: {id: 'id'},
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        })

    })
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/abc', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->id;
});
```

Here's an image of my network panel

[Screenshot of Network panel at Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwKCd.png)

Comment: Try:
`$request->all();` and show output

Comment: I changed id to all() but till nothing happened.

Comment: @GONG is correct, you can access input from AJAX requests using $request->input('id') `(EDIT)` and if you need to see your output, use `return response($request->input('id'));`

Comment: Have you included jquery files in your page and also check is there any error in your js code by using browser console or use firebug. Try to directly run ajax code through firebug console.

Comment: Yeah, check your network panel in developer tools, if u see no requests or empty parameters, then its js problem, not laravel.

Comment: You should use the network panel of your developer tools as GONG suggests. Make sure the URL that is being POST'd to is actually what you expect it to be and that the data being sent is what you want it to be.

Comment: I added jquery.min.js before $(document).ready();
I use phpstorm

Comment: @james any code suggestion how to do?

Comment: @Md.HarunOrRashid well you should start by checking the network panel as I suggested...

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to open up Google Chrome and trace the network request.

Something to bare in mind when using Laravel and AJAX, you need to pass a _token with the AJAX request if you're using either an `auth` or `web` middleware.

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/abc',
  data: {
    id: 'id',
    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
  },
  success: function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }
});
```

Please screenshot your network panel request, this will be a lot of help!

Comment: Here is the response of the request


    The requested URL was not found on this server.

  

    The link on the
    <a href="http://localhost/hsir/contact/action">referring
    page</a> seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of
    <a href="http://localhost/hsir/contact/action">that page</a>
    about the error.

Answer (score 0):

It was because:

In Laravel:

I copied the .htaccess file from public folder to the root folder and renamed the server.php file to index.php. So my public folder is one step up.
Hence url:'/abc' was not found in the server. I make the url one step up by adding two periods before the slash like url:'../abc' and problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.2 all HTTP requests goes through web middleware so you need to pass CSRF token in your Ajax header.

Put this on your js file where you perform your ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

and this one goes to your master page or necessary HTML/blade page(put it between head tags)

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

More information could be found here
https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection